# find number of automorphisms of (Z,+)

Tags: group-isomorphism

What's the number of group isomorphisms from the group (Z, +) to itself??

*my approach:
I think it has to be infinity, but that is an incorrect  answer...*

Comment: Think about $f(1)$ . Since $f$ is an isomorphism (proper term is automorphism) then where should $f(1)$ go ?

Comment: Use the group automorphism axioms / definition and you should see that it will need to fix $0$ as the additive identity.  This answer depends on the precise type of isomorphism and whether you need to fix $0$ as the identity or whether in your morphed group you could have e.g. $1$ as the additive identity instead.

Answer (score 3):

Any homomorphism of a cyclic group is determined by what it does to a generator.  So, by what it does to $1$.

But to be an automorphism, it has to be surjective.  This won't happen unless $1$ is mapped to a generator.

So we need $\varphi(1)=1$, or $\varphi(1)=-1$.  Thus there are two.

Comment: This depends upon the theorem that $\{-1,1\}$ are the only generators of $(\Bbb Z,+)$ which the OP may not already have.

Comment: @samerivertwice  This means we have to prove that $1/n$ isn't an integer for $n\ne\pm1$.  Point taken.

Comment: OP would appear to think that $x\mapsto x+i$ is an automorphism for any $i\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Yes, or some such.  But of course the only one of those that works is for $i=0$.  @samerivertwice